# Error save dbgeometry entity mysql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, spatial, spatial-query

When trying to save via entity framework entity with `DbGeometry` field type in `MySQL` I'm having trouble.

I can save a point, but `LineString` error.

Can someone help me?

[image: code]

[image: error]

Comment: Community is english-based